# Capybara with Minitest: how to make a regular assertion within a Session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

I'm working on a test with multiple sessions: an admin, an editor, a writer and a lurker.

For convenience I want to be able to mix assertions about the UI that would only be true inside the session, with regular Rails assertions (about db values, for example):

```rb
editor_session = Capybara::Session.new(:rack_test, Rails.application)
user_session = Capybara::Session.new(:rack_test, Rails.application)

user_session.do_something_in_the_ui_that_will_affect_the_db
editor_session.do_something_in_the_ui_that_will_affect_the_db

editor_session.assert(something_about_editor_that_should_now_be_true)
user_session.assert(something_about_user_that_should_now_be_true)

user_session.assert(now_cant_do_something_in_the_ui)
```

But `assert` is not a Capybara::Session method. How can I make a regular Minitest assertion here, or am I going about this the wrong way?

I know i could just make the assertion not on the session (i.e. not `user_session.assert` but just `assert`), but i've got test flows broken up into modules by session, so i'd like to be able to call a general Minitest assertion from the session.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit easier than I was imagining. You can include `Minitest::Assertions` into the session. Note: you also [have to provide](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/Minitest/Assertions) an incrementable attribute `:assertions` as well.

My module can do something like this:

```rb
class EditorIntegrationTest < CapybaraIntegrationTestCase
  def test_editor_abilities
    editor = users[:fred]
    user = users[:joon]
    editor_session = Capybara::Session.new(:rack_test, Rails.application)
    user_session = Capybara::Session.new(:rack_test, Rails.application)

    enable_editor_things(editor_session, editor)
    editor_session.should_be_able_to_do_this
    user_session.should_not_be_able_to_do_this
  end

  def enable_editor_things(session, user)
    session.extend(EditorFlow)
    session.assertions = 0
    session.user = user
  end

  module EditorFlow
    include Minitest::Assertions
    attr_accessor :user, :abilities, :text_we_are_working_on,
                  :text_description_data, :group_expectations,
                  :assertions # needed by Minitest::Assertions

    def should_be_able_to_do_this
      assert(UserGroup.editors.users.include?(user))
    end
  end
end
```